# Cycles, shade based on proximity to another object's geometry

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I am trying to make a texture that changes color based on how close one object's geometry is to another.  I've faked an example below.

[image]

I intend to use this on objects more complicated than planes, so pre-computing distances isn't reasonable.  Ideally I'd like to be able to provide a list of objects that the proximity-shader is affected by.  In particular, I don't want an object's proximity to itself to affect shading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic Paint is the perfect tool for what you're trying to achieve.[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcWXFtnh2bk) you find all information on the topic you nead.In case from some reason this tutorial will disappear,I'm talking about this:
[image]

Comment: Could you explain how to use the dynamic paint as input to a Cycles shader node?

Comment: @Mzidare, please add more detail. If the links disappears the explanation will be gone indeed making the answer incomplete (that is the very reason link-only answers are discouraged) But please do explain what you are doing on the video.

Comment: @Jason Siefken - it's a subject for a whole tutorial, so I'm not able to cover it in details here. To make long story short, you can save canvas changes as image sequence and use this sequence to influence shaders mixing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Point Dencity" texture with "Object Vertices"
[image]