# Is it possible to blend two materials on two intersecting objects?

Tags: materials

I've got two objects, each with their own distinct material, and what I'd like to do is a smooth blend between the two materials where the objects are intersecting. Is there a way to do this without connecting the two objects with a boolean? They each have their own rig/bones and I'd like to preserve those if possible, which is why I'm looking for a solution that doesn't merge them together.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-2-materials

Comment: I did see that one. Just wondered if it would also work with two separate objects rather than two materials on one object.

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67585/cycles-shade-based-on-proximity-to-another-objects-geometry and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99426/create-a-gradient-dependant-of-distance-to-an-object/99465#99465